# Enable and disble div click based on condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have the following div

```
<div class="color-block">
    <div class="common-in-block room-box">
    <p class="color-name">green</p>
    <input type="checkbox" checked value="green class="blind-value common-checkbox">
    </div>
     <div class="common-in-block room-box">
     <p class="color-name">Red</p>
     <input type="checkbox" value="red" class="blind-value common-checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="common-in-block room-box">
     <p class="color-name">Black</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="black" class="blind-value common-checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here what i need is , on the initial load of the web page i want to disable all the click event of room-box whose check box is not checked .

That is i need to disable the click of black and red cheek-box and it's corresponding parent room-box.

When user uncheck the green color then we need to enable the click of every checkbox and its parent .

That is here the condition is at a time user can only click one check box and it's corresponding parent . All the event related to unchecked checkbox and it's parent need to disabled ,. How to do this .?

For to disable click event on the unchecked check box i write the following code

```
if($(".blind-value").filter(':checked').length == 1){
        $('.blind-value:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }
    else {
        $('.blind-value').removeAttr('disabled');

        }
```

Please help to complete this

Answer (score 1):

Just bind your events to a class like "active", add or remove the class active when checkbox is checked / unchecked.

I think you can also disable click with css using: pointer-events: none;